# elasticsearch 6.2 mappings with bulk_api

Tags: json, elasticsearch, curl

I have a problem trying to insert data into elasticsearch. 
I have 1000 json files and I want to iterate over all using `curl`, using bulk API.

My json file looks like:

```
{"index": {"_index": "stuff", "_type": "text", "_id": "1"}}{"lastversion":"2018-01-19","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2018/01/microsoft-office-vulnerabilities-used-to-distribute-zyklon-malware.html"],"common_name":"anonym","samples":[{"status":"dumped","sha256":"8d0be4dd8b0ca7608bf3a02a2d212ce845ac733d150b4428376a5a939f1679ec","version":""}]}
```

What I did was:

**1. Created index named "stuff".**

`curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT "localhost:9200/stuff/"; echo`

**2. Created mappings (for most of the json file, because I did not know how to create mapping for:**

```
"samples": [
  {
    "status": "dumped",
    "sha256": "8d0be4dd8b0ca7608bf3a02a2d212ce845ac733d150b4428376a5a939f1679ec",
    "version": ""
  }
]
```

I ran the curl:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT "localhost:9200/stuff" -d'
{
 "mappings": {
  "doc": {
   "properties": {
    "updated": {"type": "keyword"},
    "attribution": {"type": "keyword"},
    "description": {"type": "keyword"},
    "notes": {"type": "keyword"},
    "alt_names": {"type": "keyword"},
    "sources": {"type": "keyword"},
    "urls": {"type": "keyword"},
    "common_name": {"type": "keyword"}
   }
  }
 }
}
'
```

**3. I have tried to upload with curl to elasticsearch cluster:**

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/x-ndjson' -XPOST "localhost:9200/stuff/_bulk" --data-binary @our.json
{"took":5,"errors":true,"items":[{"index":{"_index":"stuff","_type":"text","_id":"1","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse, document is empty"}}}]}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?
How to create mappings properly for the json provided?**

I would appreciate any feedback on that.

Comment: Could you provide us an example of the data that are you trying to send through `--data.bubart @our.json`?

Comment: data is above "My json file looks like:"

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're creating a mapping called `doc` and trying to index data with:

`{"index": {"_index": "stuff", "_type": "text", "_id": "1"}}`

That's telling ES that the next document will be part of `_type: text` that doesn't exists, if you're working with ES > 6.0 this will throw an error due you cannot have more than one type in one index.

In other hand I guess that your `our.json` it's not properly created, you must separate each sentence with `\n`.

Then your example will be like:

```
{"index": {"_index": "stuff", "_type": "text", "_id": "1"}}
{"lastversion":"2018-01-19","attribution":[],"description":"","notes":[],"alt_names":[],"sources":[],"urls":["https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2018/01/microsoft-office-vulnerabilities-used-to-distribute-zyklon-malware.html"],"common_name":"anonym","samples":[{"status":"dumped","sha256":"8d0be4dd8b0ca7608bf3a02a2d212ce845ac733d150b4428376a5a939f1679ec","version":""}]}
```